# Xamarin android c# : SQLiteAsyncConnection

Tags: c#, android, database

I'm currently using SQLiteAsyncConnection for my db coding..
I can create and insert easily into the database at almost 200 lines a second ..

My problem ... reading a database .. yes it sounds stupid .. but I need to read row by row and not dump the entire table into a variable..

Normal SQL coding has it ..
eg

```
string Oldfolder = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
        Oldfolder = Oldfolder + "/TheDatabase.db";
        SQLiteDatabase OldMydb = SQLiteDatabase.OpenDatabase(Oldfolder , null, DatabaseOpenFlags.OpenReadwrite );
        ICursor oldCheck = OldMydb.Query ("TheTable", null, null, null, null, null, null);
```

Then all you have to do is

```
oldCheck.GetString (oldCheck.GetColumnIndexOrThrow ("IDT"))
oldCheck.MoveNext();
```

Now can someone please help with the Async version?

This is how I'm inserting ....

```
var conn = new SQLiteAsyncConnection (System.IO.Path.Combine (folder, "TheDatabase.db"));
conn.CreateTableAsync<TheTable> ().ContinueWith (t => {});
TheTable myLine = new TheTable {
        TheGroup = myGroupName,
        TheTime = myMessageTime,
        TheMessage = myTextMessage,
        };
conn.InsertAsync (myLine).ContinueWith (t => {});
```

Comment: Trying to use a cursor but net getting any luck

Comment: ICursor cursor1 = Mydb1.QueryAsync("SELECT * FROM 'Table'");

"Error CS0411: The type arguments for method 'SQLite.SQLiteAsyncConnection.QueryAsync(string, params object[])' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly. (CS0411)"

Comment: trying to avoid "queryAsync <Table>"